# https certificate issue with subdomain on AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I'm running my frontend app on a DNS name like **example.com** and was able to connect the https certificate to the hosted zone in aws route 53. Now when I go to **example.com** https works fine.

The problem I have is when calling the backend.

There's a separate load balancer which runs this backend API and I want to connect it to a subdomain. Because I want a subdomain like **my.api.example.com**, from this question ([https certificate issue with subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004339/https-certificate-issue-with-subdomain))

I figured out I need a separate certificate. Then I created a new certificate that is different from example.com and *.example.com and added it to the hosted zone but there it just appears as a CNAME and I can't point it to the API load balancer.

However, I can create A Record inside the hosted zone which points to the API load balancer but then it's not secure.

My question is how to attach this separate backend api certificate to subdomain **my.api.example.com** so that when frontend running on example.com calls my.api.example.com it doesn't turn to 'Not Secure' in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the main steps that can help you to revise your current configuration.

**Step 1:**

- If you bought the certificate outside AWS, you need to import it into
  AWS ACM.
- If you issued the certificate with AWS ACM, you can move to
  the next step.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/import-certificate-api-cli.html

**Step 2:**
After successfully imported, you can validate this certificate with Route53 (or over Email).

**Step 3:**
I assumed that you are using **Application Load Balancer**. From the AWS Console, you have to create an HTTPS listener. From here, you can specify the certificate that you imported into AWS ACM earlier.

Reference:

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html
2. You can watch those steps here: https://youtu.be/GW7RkWUZL4E

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! I did buy the certificate from AWS and the only problem was the default *.example.com certificate was attached to the backend load balancer listener instead of the new one.